# как в Python прописать условие в списке со словорями

Tags: python, парсер

Подскажите, как в словаре  'cash' прописать условие. Если цены нет, то пускай идет дальше

```
def get_content(html): 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser') 
    items = soup.find_all('li', class_='ListingProductCardList_productCardListingWrapper__3-o9i') 
    cars = [] 

    for item in items: 

        cars.append({ 
            
            'cash':item.find('span',class_='PriceBlock_buyBoxPrice__3QGyjPriceBlock_buyBoxPriceStyled__29J_G').get_text(strip=type)
          

        })
 
    return cars
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое - через `try/except`, чтобы не думать, что и как проверять:

```
try:
    cars.append({ 
        'cash':item.find('span',class_='PriceBlock_buyBoxPrice__3QGyjPriceBlock_buyBoxPriceStyled__29J_G').get_text(strip=type)
    })
except:
    pass
```

Но вообще по-хорошему нужно помещать результат `item.find` в какую-то переменную, проверять через `if` её содержимое, и при наличии нужного значения уже дальше делать `cars.append`. Но это нужно смотреть что там возвращается в случае, если ничего не находит.